# What format does PrintDocument.getData() return?

Tags: android-service, android-developer-api, android-print-framework

I'm looking into what it takes to develop a PrintService on android.  After reading some on-line docs I'm not quite clear on the format of data returned by PrintDocument.getData() method.  I'd expect that in the case of PrintDocumentInfo.CONTENT_TYPE_PHOTO the returned data will be an image (I'm not quite sure about this).  However, what can I expect when content type is CONTENT_TYPE_DOCUMENT?
There is a sample of PrintDocumentInfo that uses a builder to build a pdf file.  Is this always the case?  That is, is content of CONTENT_TYPE_DOCUMENT always in pdf format?

I'd appreciate any suggestions and/or pointers to relevant on-line docs.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is always PDF for CONTENT_TYPE_DOCUMENT.